# Why doesn't ImmSetOpenStatus work the first time?

Tags: ime

I use ImmSetOpenStatus to close the input method editor under Win7 Chinese version.
However, I notice that it does not work **the first time**. Why?
Thank you.

Comment: An possible answer may be [here](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Pascal/Delphi/Q_22121530.html), but I have no access to it.

Answer (score 0):

I found it is a bug of the Sogou pinyin Chinese IME.